# Setting up LDAP authentication using question2answer.org / Uniformserver (WAMP)

Tags: php, authentication, configuration, question2answer

I have been painfully trying to configure/setup the LDAP plugin for the http://www.question2answer.org/ site.

I have the plugin installed and configured, but still I am unable to login using AD/LDAP.  The only error that comes up when I try, is "user not found".  When I look at the apache logs, nothing there to tell me what the problem is.  Nothing in the php logs either (unless I don't have the setup properly).

Anyone able to help with the install? Full files are here:
https://github.com/zakkak/qa-ldap-login/archive/master.zip

Comment: Any follow up? I've got the same problem...

Comment: Same here!  Any pointers on troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you are entering your input data wrong. 
Try querying your ldap server by hand first, for example, using `ldapsearch` command-line tool.

`ldapsearch -x -LLL -h <host ip>:<port> -D "<binding account username>" -w "<binding account password>" -b"<directory to search in(base dn)>"`

The command above gave me a long list of users, after some trials and errors(they are googleable).

If after entering your data right you get "This page isn't redirecting properly", change your email from the initial admin account so it will be not the same as your email you get from ldap. The plugin has a bug, that if one email has two users (you,as admin and you as a regular user from ldap db) it redirects you to login [infinitely](https://github.com/zakkak/qa-ldap-login/issues/10).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I have sent some patches to the project. They recently got accepted.
Please try to install again and post your findings, I will assist you.

Comment: Hey there I'm trying to setup LDAP in my Q2A site, can you provide any pointers?  I haven't got a clue how to troubleshoot, just getting the "user not found" error.